# Anyone else having trouble logging in with yahoo openid?

Tags: support, openid

This doesn't appear to be a duplicate of any of the other openid questions here.  When I try to log in using my yahoo openid on any of the new sites (which worked before on stackoverflow), it seems to be working until the redirect to "https://superuser.com/users/authenticate/?token=AS..." which is just an empty page and nothing more happens after that.

Tried in FF3 and IE6, same results on meta, superuser, and serverfault.

using myopenid works.

Answer (score 1):

I am also having problems with logging in using Yahoo.  I am getting the following error:

Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:

failed to authenticate, returning Failed. Please ensure your identifier is correct and try again.

I have tried different browsers, and have successfully logged into other OpenId sites (meta being one of them) but cannot log into stackoverflow.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This has happened to me in the past.  I think the solution for me was to just try the next day (-_-)

Comment: Or add an alternate OpenID for login?

Answer (score 0):

I had a SO user contact me earlier, saying that they had forgotten (their word) their openid, which turned out to be a yahoo mail (and no: I don't go around giving out opendids on request, before anyone asks).

I wonder if in fact this was related? i.e. it simpy wasn't working. I'll be interested to find out.

Comment: can i hab openid pls

Comment: sure thing... https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id

Answer (score 0):

There have been intermittent issues with Yahoo OpenIDs in the past but nothing systemic.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I haven't had a problem.  It may be intermittent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this error every time:

This page has expired, go back to the original page and please try again.

Oddly, I'm apparently still logged in here on meta, but I can't log in to SO.

Comment: ... and today it works. But it wouldn't work at all yesterday.